# http client got bad request page from google

Tags: http, connection, request, bad-request

I sent the following http request to google, and it returned a bad request page. Was there any wrong in my request? I was implementing a proxy server with C++. I redirected clients' requests to servers they want to connect to. Before redirecting, I inserted "\r\nConnection: close" to the request. Was the position I inserted to wrong? Thanks. (I use "@@@" to surround the request)

```
@@@GET http://www.google.com.tw/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com.tw
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: zh-tw,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Connection: close
Cookie:***

@@@
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have in there is not correct per spec, although I wouldn't be surprised if some servers actually responded to it (but not Google's).

- Proxy-Connection is a misnomer and [not needed at all](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/web-proxy-connection-header.html).
- The GET request should provide a relative path, not an absolute one. To be clear: the client does need to send a full address in the GET header, but the proxy needs to extract it and rewrite it such that GET carries the path, and Host header carries the hostname.

To try a couple of simple experiments, simply `telnet google.com 80` and copy paste your request followed by few CRLF's.